# WYSIWYG tinymce editor unwanted tags showing in drupal 7

Tags: wysiwyg

I have css define set and themes/garland  in the input for the directory but when I go to test all tags are showing.

Do I need to deselect an option in buttons to stop this or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a text format settings issue, review the formats at

*Admin > Config > Content authoring > Text Formats*

e.g *Filtered HTML > Limit allowed HTML tags*

and add the allowed tags if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Good to know about that feature but it did nothing to fix the problem on this occasion. I think I must have define css incorrectly pointed to css file. %b/sites/all/themes/mytheme/styles/styles.css